# ORACLE: parse embedded Id and match lookup

Tags: oracle

I'm looking for a little help to an interesting riddle. Just discovered a variable length id is embedded within a non conforming text field. This id is critical to a system linkage.  There is a maintained list of the 4-12 digit numeric ids that is reasonably accurate so it could be possible to match with the embedded within ids within descriptive note field VarChar2(30)

My target platforms are Oracle 12c & DataStage 8.5 to perform this. The desired result is to simply have a column with the appropriate 4-12 digit numeric id and null listed for any non matching.

Scan NOTE_DESC character for sequential numbers within string. At each term of numeric string check result value against lookup list. Something like 
loop1 (each row in table)... loop2(each NOTE_DESC character)... If numeric then enter loop3(each listvalue) to check each number in the list with nested if statements to remove  length(regexp_substr(substr(trim(t.NOTE_DESC),<>,6),'[0-9]+'))= <>

This approach is resource intensive since there's hundreds in the lookup list. I'm curious if anyone has approached a problem like this or has any code that solves this problem.

Data Example:
Independently maintained lookup List of distinct IDS: {123, 1234, 5678, 12345,  123456, 1234567 }  Meanwhile here's a list of the NOTE_DESC Field examples:

- JS 1234 Closed          (Match with desired result of 1234)
- 123456 May adjudication (Match with desired result of 123456)
- Closing Bal 5678        (Match with desired result of 5678)
- 12-3 Bal Adjustment     (No match thus null result)
- 1-23-45 Johnson         (No match thus null result)
- Vendor 123489           (No Match thus null result)

Comment: If there is more than one match, does it matter which gets picked? Perhaps the first in the order they appear in the NOTE_DESC field? Or is there an order of preference in the IDs? Or should the result have more than one row if a NOTE_DESC value matches more than one ID? Also, you are aware that 2345 will match both 23 and 234 (and also 45), right? Or is it a match only if a full string of consecutive digits is a match (so no "substring" of digits should be even looked at)? In my example, only 2345 would be a match, but 234 wouldn't match ABC2345-200?

Answer (score 0):

This may (or may not) help. First I build the two "tables" through a WITH clause (CTE, factored subqueries). I added a few more strings to `note_desc` for more testing, including one that has two matches.

Then I "prepare" the data by extracting the maximal digit substrings, keeping track of their order in the `note_desc` (the `idx` column). Finally, I compare the individual "id's" extracted from `note_desc` against the id's in the `ids` table, and finally I do a right outer join with the `note_desc` "table" to add rows for the strings that didn't have any match.

In your actual use, you may for example filter for `idx = 1` (if you only need the first match from each string), and you may choose to not show the `idx` column in the output. I left them both in so you see what everything looks like; remove what you don't need.

```
with 
     note_desc ( str ) as (
       select 'JS 1234 Closed'          from dual union all
       select '123456 May Adjudication' from dual union all
       select 'Closing Bal 5678'        from dual union all
       select '12-3 Bal Adjustment'     from dual union all
       select '1-23-45 Johnson'         from dual union all
       select 'Vendor 123489'           from dual union all
       select '2345'                    from dual union all
       select ''                        from dual union all
       select 'abckm'                   from dual union all
       select '1234-5678 xyz'           from dual
     ),
     ids ( id ) as (
       select 123     from dual union all
       select 1234    from dual union all
       select 5678    from dual union all
       select 12345   from dual union all
       select 123456  from dual union all
       select 1234567 from dual
     ),
     prep ( str, idx, id ) as (
       select str, level, regexp_substr(str, '\d+', 1, level)
       from   note_desc
       connect by regexp_substr(str, '\d+', 1, level) is not null
               and prior str = str
               and prior sys_guid() is not null
     )
select n.str, p.idx, p.id
from                    prep       p
             inner join ids        i  on p.id  = i.id
       right outer join note_desc  n  on n.str = p.str
;
```

Output (not ordered; note the NULLs)

```
STR                            IDX ID
----------------------- ---------- --------
1234-5678 xyz                    1 1234
1234-5678 xyz                    2 5678
123456 May Adjudication          1 123456
Closing Bal 5678                 1 5678
JS 1234 Closed                   1 1234

Vendor 123489
12-3 Bal Adjustment
1-23-45 Johnson
2345
abckm

11 rows selected.
```